# Как одни языки программирования отличаются от других?

Tags: любой-язык, дизайн-языка

Говорят, что Python подходит для Machine learning и научных вычислений.
Си очень быстрый.
Про другие языки ничего такого не слышал, но уверен что у них тоже есть свои особенности.

Вопрос:

1. Что означает, что один язык быстрее чем другой?
   Ведь язык программирования - это абстракция над процессорными командами. В идеале одна и та же программа на разных языках компилируется в один и тот же машинный код, т.е. процессору в итоге должны посылаться одни и те же команды.
   В таком случае, как можно говорить, что  Python быстрее PHP, а Си быстрее Java? Машинный код ведь в итоге один и тот же (в идеале).
2. И как можно утверждать, что один язык больше подходит для научных вычислений, а другой для чего-нибудь другого?
   Не понимая этой разницы, в моем понимании сейчас разные языки - это лишь разный синтаксис. И значит поставленной цели можно добиться одинаково успешно на любом языке.
3. Язык программирования - это ведь просто синтаксис, он существует только в нашей голове и в задокументированной спецификации. А чтобы этот язык понимала машина, должен быть некий интерпретатор языка. Это или компилятор или интерпретатор. Я верно понимаю?

Разницу в скорости между интерпретируемыми и компилируемыми языками не берем, тут все понятно.
И например Си не поддерживает классы, а С++ поддерживает. Тут разница тоже очевидна, поэтому речь не об этом.

Comment: У вас вопросы неправильные. Правильные вопросы такие: 1. Есть готовое решение? 2. Есть справочные материалы? 3. На SO на такое вообще отвечают?

Comment: @Hipster, это какой-то хипстерский подход

Comment: Иногда язык это ещё и своя собственная машина для его исполнения.

Comment: C - компилятор. он из программы делает сразу машинный код, причем оптимизирует его. А python - интерпретатор, он  читает программу и вызывает свои обработчики на каждую операцию. И когда вы хотите сделать a+b (типа int) на C, он буквально генерит `mov ax,a; add ax,b`, две инструкции процессора. А в питоне a+b породит вызов процедуры, которая сначала будет смотреть какого типа переменные потом складывать и выполнять еще кучу доп. работы, в итоге это будут сотни машинных команд.

Comment: У языков отличается не только синтаксис. но и подходы, парадигмы. В языках много готовых примитивов для работы с тем или иным. И с использованием этих примитивов писать программы решающие конкретные задачи гораздо быстрее и проще, чем на языках в которых нет таких примитивов. В том же питоне работа с  длинной арифметикой (типами данных превышающих размеры типов с которыми работает процессор) идет "из коробки" и вам даже задумываться не надо над тем что число может не влезть или возникнет переполнение, а в большинстве других языков размерность стандартных типов ограничена.

Comment: Ради интереса посмотрите тут вопросы с метками код-гольф (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) Там решают одни и те же задачи на многих языках. Какие то конкретные задачи, решаемые, скажем на перле, программой из 50 символов на джаве решаются программой на килобайт. И так везде, одни задачи на одних языках решаются быстро и просто, потому что языки заточены для решения именно таких задач, а другие задачи гораздо лучше решать на других языках, опять же потому что на низ гораздо быстрее можно написать

Comment: В тему @Mike: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

Answer (score 3):

В принципе, «с точки зрения вечности» вы правы в том, что идеальный компилятор подберёт идеальный, в принципе наилучший машинный код для алгоритма, который изложен в программе. Таким образом, на каком бы языке не был изложен алгоритм, должен получиться одинаковый машинный код, и разницы быть не должно.

В реальности всё обстоит не так. Идеальных компиляторов нет, и появятся ой как не скоро. Каждый из современных компиляторов тем или иным образом отдаёт часть своей работы программисту, или жертвует эффективностью ради удобства программиста.

Разница между языками программирования и компиляторами в том и состоит, что они жертвуют разными частями идеальной картины.

Возьмём, к примеру, язык C. Это системный язык, и он спроектирован так, чтобы эффективно компилироваться на компьютерах с малым количеством памяти. Поэтому он применяет только простые, легко ложащиеся на «железо» конструкции. Как результат, код получается очень быстрым, но сложные, высокоуровневые конструкции программист должен реализовать сам. У вас нет ни сборки мусора (как у C#), ни функций-как-объектов-первого-класса (как в функциональных языках), ни обобщённого кода (как в C++), ни встроенной в язык первоклассной поддержки многопоточности (как в Go). То есть язык и его стандартная библиотека разменяли удобство программирования на эффективность кода.

С другой стороны, Питон спроектирован как высокоуровневый язык, не ставящий акцент на эффективность, и не предназначенный для больших проектов. Это принесло с собой высокоуровневые типы данных (итераторы, лямбды), позднюю привязку (eval), исключения, отсутствие жёсткой типизации, нативную поддержку AOP, но реализация всего этого с необходимыми проверками обычно откладывается до времени выполнения, и тем самым производительность по сравнению с идеальным машинным кодом снижается.

---

Когда говорят о сравнении скорости языков, имеется в виду, конечно, скорость *работы* тестового алгоритма, который можно изложить легко на обоих языках. Языки, которые ставят в своём дизайне больший акцент на скорости, по этому параметру выигрывают. Разница возникает именно в том, семантически одинаковые инструкции реализуются по-разному в различных языках.

Например, в языке, в котором все массивы — ассоциативные (то есть, индексом может выступать не только число, но и, к примеру, строка), доступ по индексу обычно занимает больше времени, чем прямое вычисление адреса ячейки массива, как в языках с только числовыми индексами. Если в языке нету гарантированной безопасности типов, то приведение типа является пустой операцией, и происходит быстрее, чем в безопасном языке, в котором может понадобится проверка времени выполнения.

---

Когда говорят о пригодности языка для научных вычислений, вопрос здесь обычно в том, включает ли язык в себя, или легко ли на нём выразить конструкции, удобные для научных вычислений. Например, наличие в языке ассоциативных массивов (`std::map`, `Dictionary<K, V>`, `dict()`) даёт преимущество этому языку по сравнению с языком, в котором такую структуру данных нужно писать самому или находить чужой, не обязательно хорошо спроектированный/работающий код.

---

Машинные коды — это тоже язык. На текущий момент нету процессора, выполняющего код прямо на (например) C, а значит, для перевода с языка C на язык машинных кодов нужен *транслятор*.

Answer (score -3):

Ответы на вопросы

1. один язык быстрее чем другой - 1 язык работает напрямую с машиныым, таки assembler другие через интерпретаторы, например javascript, такие языки сначала интерптируются, транслируются а затем исполняются.
2. Одинаково успешно на любом языке . не совсем на языке javascript ты не сможешь получить доступ к железу, у него нет таких взаимодействий, остальные языки также имеют свои особенности и недостатки, некоторые отказоустойчивые, а некоторые нет
3. Язык программирования - это ведь просто синтаксис - (да язык это синтаксис, и чтобы понимала его машина нужен словарь для перевода на его язык)